# How do I make a working emacs alias function?

Tags: bash, alias, emacs, bashrc, function

In an attempt to go around an annoying aspect of tmux, I have the following code in my .bashrc file:

```
alias emcs="command emacs"

# Fix emacs in tmux
emacs () {
    if [ $TERM != "xterm" ]
    then
        TERM=xterm emacs "$@"
    else
        emacs "$@"
    fi
    return;
}
```

The alias is simply for easier access to the original emacs command.

The function is supposed to replace `emacs . . .` with `TERM-xterm emacs . . .`, regardless of the arguments listed afterward.

My problem is that when I run `emacs`, it hangs on the command line. If I change the function to "emaacs" or anything other than "emacs" then it works flawlessly. Why is it hanging when I'm using the actual name of the command, and what can I do to make it work?

---

(If you are wondering why I am doing this, it's because tmux changes the terminal to screen, which for some reason changes the emacs colors where comments and variable names are the same color.)

Comment: Your function is recursive: you need to use `command emacs` in there.

Comment: Also, you seem to always want to use xterm, so just always use it: `emacs() { TERM=xterm command emacs "$@"; }` or `alias emacs='TERM=xterm command emacs'` -- actually aliases do not recursively call themselves, so you can get away with `alias emacs='TERM=xterm emacs'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your function.  In this example, I have changed some names to indict the guilty, and struck some irrelevancies to your problem:

```
recurse{} (
    recurse "$@"
}
```

What do you think this will do when invoked?

To fix this, you can call out the explicit binary:

```
emacs () {
    if [ $TERM != "xterm" ]
    then
        TERM=xterm /usr/bin/emacs "$@"
    else
        /usr/bin/emacs "$@"
    fi
    return;
}
```

Or you can rely on your path being properly set:

```
emacs () {
    if [ $TERM != "xterm" ]
    then
        TERM=xterm command emacs "$@"
    else
        command emacs "$@"
    fi
    return;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `command` (to allow path lookup while bypassing functions and aliases) than to hard-code the path.

Answer (score 2):

```
alias emacs='TERM=xterm emacs'
```

I believe this is all you need.  It sets `TERM` to `xterm` unconditionally and runs `emacs`.

If you wish to only do this in `tmux`:

```
emacs () {
    if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
        TERM=xterm command emacs "$@"
    else
        command emacs "$@"
    fi
}
```

This uses `command` to *not* call the function recursively.  This is not needed in the alias. There is also no need to `return` in this function.